# Two step maximum likelihood

Tags: maximum-likelihood, two-step-estimation

Suppose I have a likelihood maximisation problem

$$ \hat{\theta} = \max L_n(\theta;y) $$

where $\theta = [\theta_1, \theta_2, ...., \theta_k]^T$.

What if I would estimate instead estimate the maximisation problem leaving out a parameter

$$ \hat{\theta_{-k}} = \max L_n(\theta_{-k};y) $$

but a loop over each value of $\theta_k$ and pick the specification with the highest likelihood. Would this be identical to estimating the problem jointly?

Comment: I think so. Why would you think otherwise? Evaluating each value of $\theta_{k}$ yields the profile likelihood, which is in fact handy to compute confidence intervals for a parameter (see e.g. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11222-021-10012-y ). In particular, the maximum of the profile likelihood is the MLE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align}
\max_{\theta} L_n(\theta;y) &= \max_{\theta_1,\dots,\theta_k} L_n(\theta_1,\dots,\theta_k;y) \\
&= \max_{\theta_1} \left[\max_{\theta_2}\left[\cdots \max_{\theta_k} L_n(\theta_1,\dots,\theta_k;y)\right]\right]
\end{align}
See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4417387/652310) for why the last equality is true. Any permutation of the $\max_{\theta_i}$ operators would work too.